# Disable Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools traces for a specific method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, diagnostic-tools

I'm wondering if there is a way to disable VS 2019 diagnostic tools traces **for a specific method** (using a DataAnnotation maybe ?).

I've got a method which is being called in a loop and which makes a database calls each time, ence resulting in a lot of traces like this : Execute NonQuery "xxx.xxxxxxx"...

This is also slowing down my VS a lot.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the debugging of vs2019.

Cancellation steps:

Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> General.

[image]

In this way, you can turn off debugging.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: The question was very clear that they only want to do this "for a specific method" and not disable the feature entirely

Comment: @ Martin Smith   Thanks, I'll think about it again